# CMake libraries issue

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, makefile, cmake, libraries

I'm trying to compile a program that uses the URG (Laser scanner) library along with PCL. URG uses make to build but PCL uses cmake. I've been trying to use cmake for both but i've been having issues.

I found FindURG.cmake and put it in the modules folder here: https://github.com/wicron/vlidar/blob/master/cmake/FindURG.cmake

My CMakeLists is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MY_GRAND_PROJECT)

find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

find_package(URG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${URG_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${URG_LIBRARY})

#add_executable(pcd_write_test pcd_write.cpp)
add_executable(urg_read_test  gdScanSample.cpp)

#target_link_libraries(pcd_write_test  ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(urg_read_test ${URG_LIBRARY})

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "-I/usr/local/include/urg")
#SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-I/usr/local/include/urg")
```

PCL is found fine, URG is also found as shown below. The directories look fine too.

```
root@CCSL02:/home/marwan/pcl_sample# cmake CMakeLists.txt
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- Found c_urg libraries. /usr/local/lib/libc_urg_system.so/usr/local/lib/libc_urg.so/usr/local/lib/libc_urg_connection.so/usr/lib/liburg.so/usr/lib/liburg_connection.so/usr/lib/liburg_system.so/usr/lib/liburg_common.so/usr/lib/liburg_coordinate.so/usr/lib/liburg_geometry.so
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/marwan/pcl_sample
```

But as soon as I run make, here's what I get:

```
root@CCSL02:/home/marwan/pcl_sample# make
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/urg_read_test.dir/gdScanSample.cpp.o
/home/marwan/pcl_sample/gdScanSample.cpp:10:21: fatal error: UrgCtrl.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/urg_read_test.dir/gdScanSample.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/urg_read_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've tried to play with the CMakeLists in which I tried added the CXX flags but no luck

It should be noted that the following makefile compiles the urg program normally

```
# Makefile for urg_sample
# Satofumi KAMIMURA
# $Id: Makefile 1997 2012-10-30 02:57:51Z satofumi $

CXXFLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall -Werror `urg-config --cflags` `sdl-config --cflags`
LDFLAGS =
LDLIBS = `urg-config --libs` `sdl-config --libs` -lc

TARGET = gdScanSample

all : $(TARGET)

clean :
    $(RM) *.o $(TARGET)

.PHONY : all clean
```

Comment: Do *not* use `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` for specifying include directories (this is what `include_directories` and `target_include_directories` are for). In fact, do not use it for *anything*, there are almost always better alternatives available with modern CMake. Try sprinkling some [`message`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:message) commands in your script to verify that the variables obtained by the find script contain the values you expect.

Comment: @ComicSansMS Good call, URG_INCLUDE_DIR was just /usr/local/include. adding /urg at the end fixed the error. include_directories(${URG_INCLUDE_DIR}/urg)

However, I'm getting a new one 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lURG
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Note: URG_LIBRARY is /usr/local/lib/libc_urg.so

Comment: @ComicSansMS Ignore my last comment, I'm actually getting all these undefined reference to functions:

gdScanSample.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `qrk::UrgCtrl::UrgCtrl()'
gdScanSample.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `qrk::UrgCtrl::connect(char const*, long)'
...

Comment: Can you check the output of the `urg-config --libs` call that is used in the original Makefile? Compare it to the `${URG_LIBRARY}` obtained by the find script.

Comment: @ComicSansMS urg-config --libs returns -lurg_monitor -lurg -lurg_coordinate -lurg_geometry -lurg_connection -lurg_connection_sdl -lurg_common -lurg_system -lm

while ${URG_LIBRARY} is a path: /usr/local/lib/libc_urg.so

Comment: @ComicSansMS Actually URG_LIBRARIES is the one I should use and it outputs /usr/local/lib/libc_urg_system.so/usr/local/lib/libc_urg.so/usr/local/lib/libc_urg_connection.so/usr/lib/liburg.so/usr/lib/liburg_connection.so/usr/lib/liburg_system.so/usr/lib/liburg_common.so/usr/lib/liburg_coordinate.so/usr/lib/liburg_geometry.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to ComicSansMS

Here's a working CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
project(MY_GRAND_PROJECT)

find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED)#COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

find_package(URG REQUIRED)
include_directories(${URG_INCLUDE_DIR}/urg)
link_directories(${URG_LIBRARIES}) 

add_executable(pcd_write_test pcd_write.cpp)

target_link_libraries(pcd_write_test  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}  ${URG_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that `SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "-I/usr/local/include/urg")` points to the directory where all the h files are. Maybe you will need to add more than one location.

Comment: I got the directory by running urg-config --cflags

I've also tried SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-I/usr/local/include/urg -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT") which is the output of urg-congig and sdl-config --cflags. If I change CMAKE_C_FLAGS to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS I get undefined reference to the functions.

Comment: Where does `PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS` come from?
I think this should include the actual directory where the h files are in.
Same for `PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS` and external libraries.

Comment: It comes from FindPCL.cmake. **No problem** at all with pcl. Its the URG library that's not compiling.